# how to reference hadoop v2.3.0 jars in maven?

Tags: maven, hadoop, maven-3

i am simply trying to reference the hadoop mapreduce jar in my maven project. i see that the way to do so is posted at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce/2.3.0.

my pom has the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
 <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce</artifactId>
 <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

however, in eclipse, i see the following errors.

1. The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library `C:\Users\root\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce\2.3.0\hadoop-mapreduce-2.3.0.jar`
2. The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
3. Missing artifact `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce:jar:2.3.0`

how to reference hadoop v2.3.0 jars in maven?

when i type in the following command

`mvn clean install -e -X -U`

i see the following output

`Could not find artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce:jar:2.3.0 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)`

any idea on what's going on here?

by the way, my `~/.m2/settings.xml` has not been "tampered" with. it's still the default one that's placed there.

here's some information on my maven version.

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 08:51:28-0500)
Maven home: C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_13, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works (Notice type is pom as this is container for other modules):

```
  <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
 <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce</artifactId>
 <version>2.3.0</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
 <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
```

But usually for development i use (it packages all relevant dependencies):

```
  <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
 <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
 <version>2.3.0</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
 <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: thank you. that worked. i will search for scope and type for maven dependency. if you have time, could you please explain why if this is the way to reference these dependencies, why is it not shown as such at mvnrepository.com ?